# How to render only three data elements each time when you click on load more? Backbone

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby, backbone.js, haml

I have a list of card elements and each of these card contains some info. With a load more option, I am trying to load only three card elements at a time and by default only two are loaded initially. Below is my view file:

```
(function() {
  var __extends = function(child, parent) { for (var key in parent) { 
if (__hasProp.call(parent, key)) child[key] = parent[key]; } function 
ctor() { this.constructor = child; } ctor.prototype = parent.prototype; 
child.prototype = new ctor(); child.__super__ = parent.prototype; 
return child; },
__hasProp = {}.hasOwnProperty;

  TalentCardNew.Views.CertificationCard = (function(_super) {
__extends(CertificationCard, _super);

function CertificationCard() {
  return CertificationCard.__super__.constructor.apply(this, arguments);
}

CertificationCard.prototype.template = JST['talent_card_new/templates/common/certification_card'];

CertificationCard.prototype.className = 'certification-container';

CertificationCard.prototype.events = {
  'click .listCertificatesContainer': 'showMoreCertificates'
};

CertificationCard.prototype.initialize = function(options) {
  if (options == null) {
    options = {};
  }
  this.view_type = options.view_type;
  this.card_data = new Backbone.Collection();
  this.card_data.add(new Backbone.Model({
    name: "Accounting Qualification Excellence",
    place: "Accounting Institue",
    valid_till: "Dec 14, 2018"
  }));
  this.card_data.add(new Backbone.Model({
    name: "Accounting Qualification Excellence",
    place: "Accounting Institue",
    valid_till: "Dec 14, 2018"
  }));
  this.card_data.add(new Backbone.Model({
    name: "Accounting Qualification Excellence",
    place: "Accounting Institue",
    valid_till: "Dec 14, 2018"
  }));
  this.card_data.add(new Backbone.Model({
    name: "Accounting Qualification Excellence",
    place: "Accounting Institue",
    valid_till: "Dec 14, 2018"
  }));
  this.card_data.add(new Backbone.Model({
    name: "Accounting Qualification Excellence",
    place: "Accounting Institue",
    valid_till: "Dec 14, 2019"
  }));
  this.card_data.add(new Backbone.Model({
    name: "Accounting Qualification Excellence",
    place: "Accounting Institue",
    valid_till: "Dec 14, 2018"
  }));
  this.card_data.add(new Backbone.Model({
    name: "Accounting Qualification Excellence",
    place: "Accounting Institue",
    valid_till: "Dec 14, 2018"
  }));
  return this.card_data.add(new Backbone.Model({
    name: "Accounting Qualification Excellence",
    place: "Accounting Institue",
    valid_till: "Dec 14, 2019"
  }));
};

CertificationCard.prototype.render = function() {
  $(this.el).html(this.template({
    view_type: this.view_type,
    card_data: this.card_data
  }));
  if (this.view_type === 'my_profile') {
    this.renderModal();
  }
  this.renderLoadMore();
  return this;
};

CertificationCard.prototype.renderModal = function() {
  var popup_view;
  popup_view = new TalentCardNew.Views.AddCertification();
  return $(this.el).find('#modalContainer').html(popup_view.render().el);
};

CertificationCard.prototype.renderLoadMore = function() {
  if ((this.view_type === 'my_profile' && this.card_data.length > 2) || (this.card_data.length > 3)) {
    return $(this.el).find('.listCertificatesContainer').removeClass('hide');
  }
};

return CertificationCard;

})(Backbone.View);

}).call(this);
```

Also my Haml code is below:

```
- now = new Date()
- if @view_type == 'my_profile'
  %button.certification-card.add-certification-card{"data-target" => 
"#certificationModal", "data-toggle" => "modal"}
    %i.avatar--icon.fa.fa-plus-circle
    %elabel= ECL.t('add', default_value: "Add")
- _.each @card_data.models, (data) =>
  - expire_date = "#{data.get('valid_till')}"
  - actual_date = new Date(expire_date)
  .certification-card
    .avatar--icon.fa.fa-users
    .details
      .title= "#{data.get('name')}"
      .caption= "#{data.get('place')}"
      - if actual_date < now
        .meta-text= "Valid Till: #{data.get('valid_till')}"
      - else
        .meta-text= "Expired On: #{data.get('valid_till')}"
%button.btn-more.listCertificatesContainer.hide
  Load More
#modalContainer
```

Here I am trying to display the entire two certification-card by default and load the rest three at a times only on click of load more.Help woould be appreciated

Comment: Side note: you can just do `this.card_data = new Backbone.Collection([/*array of objects*/]);` and the objects will be initialized as models, instead of manually doing i one by one...

Comment: Also you can use `this.$el` instead of  `$(this.el)` and `this.$('#modalContainer')` instead of `$(this.el).find('#modalContainer')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like this (pseudo code) :

```
CertificationCard.prototype.initialize = function() {
  this.currentIndex = 0;
  this.loadMoreIncrement = 3
  this.render(2);
};

CertificationCard.prototype.render = function(increment) {
  const newIndex = this.currentIndex + increment;
  cost models = this.card_data.slice(this.currentIndex, newIndex);
  this.$el.append(this.renderCards(models));
  this.currentIndex = newIndex;
};

CertificationCard.prototype.renderCards = function(models) {
  return this.template({
    view_type: this.view_type,
    card_data: models
  });
};

CertificationCard.prototype.renderLoadMore = function() {
  this.render(this.loadMoreIncrement);
};
```

Comment: This work, but the problem is along with the appending of certificate card, it also append the rest of the html element.Now if I add the an id in the html and tell the card to append only on this id, with this I can call a method to append repeatedly on that div. However the UI breaks because now the cards append only on the same div

Comment: @MaheshMesta Sorry I didn't fully understand above comment, sounds like you need to render a single card to specific element?
Currently what you have is something that we call a "CollectionView", it looks like you need an "itemView" as well.. What you do is separate the HTML to render 1 item to a new template, create a view for it (`CertificationCard`), then create another view that renders a collection of them (`CertificationCards`).
Maybe I misunderstood the problem, but look into "rendering collection views" in backbone, if not maybe ask a new question showing the problem?

Comment: yes I realized that. Made a different html template for each item card. Works fine for me